# Azure Calculator API: How do I get expected network bandwidth metrics?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-calculator

I am working on building out a report that will help team members make decisions on VM types for Azure deployments.  One of the data points I'm being asked to provide is the "Expected network bandwidth" for each type.  ([See this link for an example of the metric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/av2-series))

In the [Virtual Machine Sizes REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machine-sizes/list#virtualmachinesizelistresult), there is no mention of expected network bandwidth.  Where can I get that information? Is there another API that I can hit to get more detailed information about virtual machine SKUs?

The information that is returned from that API looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Standard_B1ls",
  "numberOfCores": 1,
  "osDiskSizeInMB": 1047552,
  "resourceDiskSizeInMB": 4096,
  "memoryInMB": 512,
  "maxDataDiskCount": 2
}
```

Comment: Bandwidth (network ingress and egress) is something that you guestimate based upon your application design. Bandwidth (network traffic) is a separate billing item and is not included with VMs.

Comment: @JohnHanley, thanks for the comment.  I'm looking for where the data from the first link comes from, not the network ingress and egress data.  I cannot find any API that gives me the Max NIC count nor the Expected Network Bandwidth given a specific VM Type. I'm assuming since those 2 metrics are shown inline with other VM metrics, that they would be attributable to a VM. Am I not correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use resource sku list rest api to get more details on the sku .

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/skus?api-version=2019-04-01
```

I tested the above and I could see more details like IOPS and No. of Nic's etc , but there is no expected network bandwidth.

[image]

I tried to check with az cli as well , but it seems its not possible to get expected bandwidth from anywhere.

```
az vm list-skus -l eastus2 --size Standard_A1_v2
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Resource Skus - List - REST API (Azure Compute) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/resource-skus/list)

[az vm | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_list_sizes)